# PySpark - assigning group id based on group member count

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe where I want to assign id in for each window partition and for each 5 rows. Meaning, the id should increase/change when the partition has a different value or the number of rows in a partition is more than 5.

Input:

```
id | group |
1  |   A   |
2  |   A   |
3  |   A   |
4  |   A   |
5  |   A   |
6  |   A   |
7  |   A   |
8  |   A   |
9  |   B   |
10 |   B   |
11 |   C   |
12 |   C   |
```

Expected output:

```
id | group | group_id 
1  |   A   | 1
2  |   A   | 1
3  |   A   | 1
4  |   A   | 1
5  |   A   | 1
6  |   A   | 2
7  |   A   | 2
8  |   A   | 2
9  |   B   | 3
10 |   B   | 3
11 |   C   | 4
12 |   C   | 4
```

I tried a dense_rank approach, followed by udf. However, I cannot figure out how to carry over the previous rank value if I need to change the rank due to "*for each 5 rows*" constraint.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

window = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('id')
df_rank = df.withColumn('group_rank', F.dense_rank().over(window))

group_size = 5
# +1 in group_size to include 5, and +1 after the division to avoid rank 0
map_func = F.udf(lambda x: int(x / (group_size+1)) + 1, IntegerType())
df_rank_map = df_rank.withColumn('group_id', map_func(df_rank.group_rank))
```

Output:

```
id | group | group_rank | group_id
1  |   A   | 1          | 1
2  |   A   | 2          | 1
3  |   A   | 3          | 1
4  |   A   | 4          | 1
5  |   A   | 5          | 1
6  |   A   | 6          | 2
7  |   A   | 7          | 2
8  |   A   | 8          | 2
9  |   B   | 1          | 1
10 |   B   | 2          | 1
11 |   C   | 1          | 1
12 |   C   | 2          | 1
```

From my code, there are 2 problems. The obvious one is that the group_id is no where, what I want. I have yet to figure out a logic to carry over the previous rank to the next group.
The second problem is that, due to the udf, this logic is really slow. It would be really nice, if there is a way that also improve the performance.

I have been pulling my hair to figure out a way to do this. However, to no avail. Any idea or hint how to achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign each distinct value of `group` a number, multiply this number with a sufficient large constant and then add the integer part of `group_rank / 5`.

First assign each element of the group column a unique number:

```python
group_idx=df.select('group').distinct().withColumn('group_idx', F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('group')))
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------+
|group|group_idx|
+-----+---------+
|    A|        1|
|    B|        2|
|    C|        3|
+-----+---------+
```

Now calculate the group id:

```python
window = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('id')
df.withColumn('group_rank', F.dense_rank().over(window)) \
  .withColumn("idx_within_group", (F.col('group_rank') / F.lit(5)).cast('int')) \
  .join(group_idx, 'group') \
  .withColumn('group_id', F.col('group_idx') * 100 + F.col('idx_within_group')) \
  .select('id', 'group', 'group_id') \
  .orderBy('id') \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+--------+
| id|group|group_id|
+---+-----+--------+
|  1|    A|     100|
|  2|    A|     100|
|  3|    A|     100|
|  4|    A|     100|
|  5|    A|     101|
|  6|    A|     101|
|  7|    A|     101|
|  8|    A|     101|
|  9|    B|     200|
| 10|    B|     200|
| 11|    C|     300|
| 12|    C|     300|
+---+-----+--------+
```

Using `100` as multiplier is a bit arbitary. This number has to be larger than the `(number of elements in the largest group) / 5`.
If you need strictly consecutive numbers as group_ids this approach won't work.

Comment: Although I cannot use the 10x, 20x,... value in the group_id as I need to convert the value later into string and pad them, your approach did the core problem already.
I can take it from where you left off. Thank you so much for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe with the sample values(assuming you have initialized spark)

```
data  = [(9,"B"), (10,"B"), (11,"C"), (12,"C"), (1,"A"), (2,"A"), (3,"A"), (4,"A"), (5,"A"), (6,"A") , (7,"A"),(8,"A")]

columns = ["id","group"]

df_org = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
```

Import all the required libraries

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

Create a reference dataframe to calculate the count

```
windowspec1 = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('group')
df1 = df.withColumn('group_count',count('group').over(windowspec1))
```

Then take out distinct values from that and apply monotonically_increasing_id()

```
df1_temp = df1.select('group','group_count').distinct()
windowspec2 = Window.partitionBy('group_count').orderBy('group_count')
df1_temp = df1_temp.withColumn('rank',monotonically_increasing_id()+1)
```

Finally, join the reference dataframe with the main dataframe that you had.

```
df_final = df_org.join(df1_temp,on = ['group'],how ='left')
df_final.show()
```

This is the sample output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhaVn.png)

Comment: Your approach is unfortunately insufficient.  For every 5 records, I also need to increase the rank. And that is where I have a problem.
From your sample output, ID 1-5 (group A) will have rank 1, 6-8 (group A) rank 2, 9-10 (group B) rank 3, 11-12 (group C) rank 4.